# Como é possível responder uma pergunta fechada?

Tags: bug

Nesta pergunta, [Como crio um tema para textarea igual do VS Code?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395504/5878), podemos ver que a resposta foi publicada depois que a pergunta foi fechada.

**Pergunta fechada às 13:33 do dia 05/07**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resposta publicada às 13:51 do dia 05/07**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como foi possível publicarem uma resposta quase 20 min após a pergunta ser fechada?

Comment: E esse não foi um caso insolado, já aconteceu outras vezes em que eu fechei perguntas como sendo Duplicadas... http://prntscr.com/ohccfy e aqui a pergunta foi fechada as 13:33 e por coincidência ou não o mesmo usuário respondeu as 13:51 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396728/esconder-arquivos-do-inspecionar